# Tab completion for filetypes in the commandline

Tags: command-line, filetype, autocompletion

If I  want to set the filetype manually in vim, I would like to tab complete filetypes vim recognizes. However, right now vim just inserts a literal `^I`

```
:set ft=markd^I
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Builtin command `:setfiletype`

For setting the filetype there is additionally a dedicated vim command `:setfiletype` which supports tab completion and `<C-d>`:

```
:setfiletype mar<tab>
:setfiletype <C-d>
```

The command can be abbreviated as following:

```
:setf mar<tab>
:setf <C-d>
```

#### Plugin fzf.vim

The plugin [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) provides furthermore the command `:Filetypes`.

```
:Filet[ypes]<CR>
> prompt
```

At the prompt you can enter a filetype with fuzzy matching e.g. `mkd` for `markdown` or `jsc` for `javascript`.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, we cannot add completion to standard commands.

You'll have to define your own `:SetFT` command and complete with `-complete=filetype`
Something like:

```
" untested
command! -nargs=1 -complete=filetype SetFt :set ft=<args>
```

Comment: That's too bad. I'd like to stick with the default command and would rather try to ask a vim developer to support it. But I guess this won't happen. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Honestly, there is no reason it can't be done. You can try to open a Feature Request issue on vim github. Who knows?